# Change today, yesterday and this week's dates to relative, human-readable format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm pulling in some tweets and I'd love to output whether or not they came in today, yesterday, or before that. Here's the code that I'm working with (which doesn't work). It's skipping the *if* and *else if* and going straight to the *else*.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$time = $block["created_at"];
$time = strtotime($time);

if(date("now") == date("m-d-Y", $time)) {
    $time = date("g:ia", $time);
}
else if(date(strtotime("-1 day")) == date("m-d-Y", $time)) {
    $time = "Yesterday at" + date("g:ia", $time);
}
else {
    $time = date("m-d-Y g:ia", $time);
}
```

Absolutely ideally, I'd also love it if, when the timestamp falls within the last 6 days, it shows the day of the week and the time, and anything older than that will show the date.

So the stream might look like this (dates sorted descending):

> [...] 9:53am
>   [...] 7:02am
>   [...] Yesterday at 11:24pm
>   [...] Monday at 3:45pm
>   [...] Jan 2, 2013

Any idea as to where my code is going awry? Thanks!

Comment: `if(date("m-d-Y") == date("m-d-Y", $time))` should take care of first if.

Comment: Also take care of `date("now")`

Comment: With @Salman's help, I figured out Today and Yesterday. Now I'm just trying to figure out the "older than 6 days" part.

Comment: But if he depends on the server date it won't work all the time.. because it's changeable. Try to store the date you insert the twits then it will be note easy to compare the dates and time.

Comment: Please examine the operands to the conditionals and you'll be able to see why they don't match. Debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function can parse various strings:

```
echo date("D Y-m-d H:i:s");                               // Wed 2013-01-09 21:33:07
echo date("D Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("today 00:00" ));    // Wed 2013-01-09 00:00:00
echo date("D Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("yesterday 00:00")); // Tue 2013-01-08 00:00:00
echo date("D Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-6 day 00:00" ));   // Thu 2013-01-03 00:00:00
echo date("D Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-100 day 00:00" )); // Mon 2012-10-01 00:00:00
```

All you need to do now is to compare the given timestamp with the above in descending order:

```
function formatDate($time) {
    if ($time >= strtotime("today 00:00")) {
        return date("g:i A", $time);
    } elseif ($time >= strtotime("yesterday 00:00")) {
        return "Yesterday at " . date("g:i A", $time);
    } elseif ($time >= strtotime("-6 day 00:00")) {
        return date("l \\a\\t g:i A", $time);
    } else {
        return date("M j, Y", $time);
    }
}

echo formatDate(time());                 // 9:42 PM
echo formatDate(strtotime("-1 day"));    // Yesterday at 9:42 PM
echo formatDate(strtotime("-6 day"));    // Thursday at 9:42 PM
echo formatDate(strtotime("-100 day"));  // Oct 10, 2012
```

Note that `strtotime()` returns a timestamp (an integer) while `date()` returns a  string. The function compares timestamps with timestamp.

Comment: `return date("M n, Y", $time)` should probably be `return date("M d, Y", $time)`. `date('n')` is the numeric month, not the day of the month.

Answer (score 6):

Your code should look liike below.

```
if(date("m-d-Y") == date("m-d-Y", $time)) {
    $time = date("g:ia", $time);
}
else if(date("m-d-Y", strtotime("-1 day")) == date("m-d-Y", $time)) {
    $time = "Yesterday at" + date("g:ia", $time);
}
else {
    $time = date("m-d-Y g:ia", $time);
}
```

***Explanation***

date() — Format a local time/date. Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of `time()`.

***Where have you gone wrong ?***

You should 1st pass the format then the timestamp to the `date()` function. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: While you have answered the question. You have provided no explanation.